# Output of large numbers

Tags: c++

I need to use a high Number in my program. Here is an minimum example that shows the problem. It just reads in a number and gives out the number again.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double 
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    cout << N << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine till 10^9 If I take 10^10 as input the result is 1.41007e+09. I just don't know why this is the case. I already tried the following:

- Change the Datatype of N to double, long int, unsigned int
- Define the Number directly in the program with N = pow(10,10). When I put out N **and** pow(10,10) directly, N gives the wrong value and pow(10,10) the right one.

Comment: You **do** realize that `atoi()` stands for "ASCII to **Integer**"? And that data types have limits? If you don't, check documentation for `atoi()` and `limits.h`.

Comment: did you try `double N = pow(10, 10);`

Comment: Read about [`std::stold`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) (or optionally about [`std::strtold`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)). Or [`std::stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) ([`std::strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)) if you want integers.

Comment: How big a number are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `atoi` when the resulting value would be outside the bounds of `int` (i.e. greater than `INT_MAX` or less than `INT_MIN`) causes undefined behaviour.

This is a good reason to not use `atoi`. The alternatives `strtol` and `strtoul` from the C library have well-defined behaviour for all inputs.

The C++11 function `std::stoi` also has well-defined behaviour (it throws an exception if the value is out of range). `istream::operator>>(int&)` is also well-defined but it has some finicky details relating to the fact that streams can't "look ahead".

Answer (score 0):

Using atoi on the number greater than INT_MAX will cause the resultant value to start from the negative value INT_MIN.

Try using atoll function. It is in . But this is defined in C++11. So, if your compiler is not up-to-date than it will throw an error.

If the value is again quite large (greater than 8 bytes), then I would suggest you to use external libraries.

Answer (score -1):

The input 10^10 goes beyond the maximum limit of an integer that is 2147483648 and 10^9 is well within the limit.

Following code can be useful.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    long long N = atoll (argv[1]);
    cout << N << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain why and explain the limits and explain _something_. Just randomly substituting `long long` everywhere, which is what you are training this OP to do, is incredibly reckless.

Comment: What is the proper answer to the problem then? How to get the input 10^10?

Comment: You didn't address my comment at all.

Comment: The input 10^10 goes beyond the maximum limit of an integer that is 2147483648 and 10^9 is well within the limit.