# Why is multiply of two size_t's wrong?

Tags: macos, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    size_t foo = 600000000;
    size_t bar = 8;
    size_t foobar = foo * bar;
    printf ("%lu * %lu is %lu\n",foo,bar,foobar);
}
```

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.c
$ ./hello
600000000 * 8 is 505032704
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.1 20090623 (prerelease)
```

Mac OS X 10.7.5

The native cc (Clang) compiler produces correct results.  But I use gcc/gfortran on multiple platforms.

Comment: Why do you believe it is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402815/output-of-large-numbers this seems related

Comment: The correct format for `size_t` is `"%zu"`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an overflow problem.  Your issue is that your compiler is creating 32-bit code.

600000000 * 8 is 4800000000.
2^32 is 4294967296.

Since size_t is 4 bytes on a 32 bit system, assuming it is unsigned, and accounting for overflow, we get:

4800000000 - 4294967296, which is 505032704.

You should be able to find a 64-bit compiler (which it seems the native cc Clang compiler is), but you would be better off using specifically 64-bit types (instead of size_t).

Comment: OK, thanks.  I could see a 32 bit truncation was happening, but I had falsely assumed my compiler would make size_t 64 bits.  What fixes the problem is much simpler than finding a new compiler (though it might be time for that).  I just use -m64 option and it works correctly.

Comment: Glad you found an easy fix.